# Tracking an image after adding to media scanner (when an user selects it from the gallery)

Tags: android, image, android-contentresolver

I have an app that allows users to take images from their camera that get saved to the SD card and I run the media scanner on it so they are visible in the gallery. Users can also add images from the gallery.

I do some compression on the image before saving to SD card. So, when a user selects an image from gallery, if it was an image that was compressed and written by my app, I want to avoid it from getting compressed again. I was thinking of checking the image path to figure out if the image was from my app, but with URIs, I get strings like `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A38691` and uri.getPath() doesn't seem to have the path.

What are my options to figure out if this image was from my app? Here are the things I can think of:

1) `Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file)`: This seems to be giving a value of `file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyApp/image.jpg`

2) Store a checksum of the data when I write to the SD card and check against this when I see the new image.

3) Somehow get the URI when the media scanner is run. Haven't figured out how to do this yet.

UPDATE: for option (3), looks like I can use a `MediaScannerConnectionClient`. Is this the best option? Store the path to URI mapping in a DB and refer to that each time the user adds a new image to my app from the gallery.

Comment: Why not save something in the image metadata (exif or whatever) when you compress it?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: oh, thats a nice idea. Let me try that out, would be the simplest way to go about this.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: When I try to get the Exif data for the file, I run in to a similar issue as the ExifInterface provided by Android takes a file path. Tried searching on how to extract Exif info from an URI and can't seem to find a reliable way. Do you have any thoughts on this?